# Reading live output of application when its already running

Tags: java, unix, weblogic, stdout, redhat

**My setup:**

- Red Hat *with:*
- Weblogic installation which hosts my (java) application.

**What I try to achieve:**
See the output (an error) of my application

**Why I this way and not easier (set proper logging on the application itself):**

- This is a production server of a big company, I am not allowed to do any changes to the running applications
- In the application something goes wrong and I am tasked with fixing it.
- I checked the weblogic logs but they dont capture all the output of the application, and thus it does not capture the error im searching for.

So is there a way I can sort of connect to stdout/stderr and see the output printed live? (other suggestions are also most welcome but if its possible this seems like the easiest way to go?)

Extra info:

- I have checked and confirmed the application writes to console, so it should appear in stdout. (right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your question, you want to tail the logs.

Navigate to the directory where your logs are stored and run

```
tail -f LOGNAME.log
```

This should print to your console live any additional log lines that are added.

Comment: if the server is started with "nohup" you can have a look to the nohup.out file
Check also if your server is started with the following properties that will redirect stdout and stderr to correspondig files : `-Dweblogic.Stdout=STDOUT.LOG -Dweblogic.Stderr=STDERR.LOG`

Comment: nohup was indeed the answer. Together with tail I achieved the goal